# Getting error: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Tags: python, django

I have a project where the user can register and then he is getting a confirmation email. The project is working fine on my local computer but after I deployed the project on pythonanywhere I am getting this error when a client tries to register:not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
Also the email is not send but I can see him on the admin panel. I hope you can help.

views.py

```
def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        # return redirect('home')
        return redirect('/login')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Activation link is invalid!')

def confirmation_phase(request):
    return render(request, 'confirm_email.html')

def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            mail_subject = 'Hesabınızı Aktifleştirin.'
            message = render_to_string('acc_activate_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token':account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            email = EmailMessage(
                        mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]
            )
            email.send()
            return redirect('/confirmation_phase')
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://itucampus.pythonanywhere.com/signup/

Django Version: 3.1
Python Version: 3.8.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'crispy_forms',
 'ad',
 'distribution',
 'account',
 'homepage',
 'forum',
 'questions',
 'newstudentwp']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/itucampus/.virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 62, in forbid_multi_line_headers
    val.encode('ascii')

During handling of the above exception ('ascii' codec can't encode character '\u0130' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)), another exception occurred:
  File "/home/itucampus/.virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/itucampus/.virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "./account/views.py", line 40, in signup
    email.send()
  File "/home/itucampus/.virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 284, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/home/itucampus/.virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 109, in send_messages
    sent = self._send(message)
  File "/home/itucampus/.virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 123, in _send
    message = email_message.message()
  File "/home/itucampus/.virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 249, in message
    msg['From'] = self.extra_headers.get('From', self.from_email)
  File "/home/itucampus/.virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 162, in __setitem__
    name, val = forbid_multi_line_headers(name, val, self.encoding)
  File "/home/itucampus/.virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 65, in forbid_multi_line_headers
    val = ', '.join(sanitize_address(addr, encoding) for addr in getaddresses((val,)))
  File "/home/itucampus/.virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 65, in <genexpr>
    val = ', '.join(sanitize_address(addr, encoding) for addr in getaddresses((val,)))
  File "/home/itucampus/.virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 97, in sanitize_address
    localpart, domain = address.rsplit('@', 1)

Exception Type: ValueError at /signup/
Exception Value: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

email settings

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'itucampusdestek@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*******'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'İTÜ CAMPUS Team'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

Comment: The problem is in your `signup` view. The email address you use, does not contain an `@`.

Comment: Your `from_email` is likely not a valid email address.

Comment: What does your `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL` setting look like?

Comment: I edited in the question

Comment: well `'İTÜ CAMPUS Team' ` is not a valid email address. What if you use the `'itucampusdestek@gmail.com'` instead?

Comment: it worked, thank you very much but why have I to enter my email address twice

Comment: The first time you enter it, as `EMAIL_HOST_USER`, it's the username to use when logging in to the email server.  The second time you specify it, as `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL`, it's the email address that you're sending from.  In many cases these would be different values.